How to change logging directory in ROS Python?
I'm using ROS with Python and attempting to change the logging directory by setting the ROS_LOG_DIR environment variable programmatically. I've used the following code to set the environment variable:
import os
os.environ['ROS_LOG_DIR'] = log_filepath

However, when I launch my node using roslaunch, the logging directory still defaults to ~/.ros/log.
Has anyone encountered this issue or know how to correctly set the logging directory for ROS nodes in Python? Is there a different approach or configuration required to make this work?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Can you try to export it in your ~/.bashrc file?
nano ~/.bashrc
export ROS_LOG_DIR=<log_filepath>
save and exit.
Then close all your terminals and run your code again.
